# WCF: There was no channel actively listening

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I created a WCF rest service in my ASP.NET (C#) application, and it seems to be **working fine** when I try to browse to it via web browser at the following
localhost:81/ExternalServices/WS/SPP/REST/SPPService.svc

However, if I try to hit one of its methods, I get the below error message:
localhost:81/ExternalServices/WS/SPP/REST/SPPService.svc/GetDetails

**Message**: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://MachineName.abc.local:81/ExternalServices/WS/SPP/REST/SPPService.svc/GetDetails'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.

**Contract**:

```
namespace ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISPPService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetProductionDetail")]
        string GetProductionDetail(Stream data);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetDetails();
    }
}
```

**Implementation**:

```
namespace ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =  AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class SPPService : ISPPService
    {
        public string GetProductionDetail(Stream xmlRequest)
        {
            return "hello";
        }

        public string GetDetails()
        {
            return "hello2";
        }
    }
}
```

**The .SVC File (SPPService.svc)**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service = "ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST.SPPService" Language="C#" %>
```

**Web.Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.Disb.Rest.DisbService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviour">
    <endpoint name="webHttpsBinding" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.Disb.Rest.IDisbService"
       behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>
  <service name="ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST.SPPService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviour">
    <endpoint name="webHttpsBinding" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST.ISPPService"
       behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>      
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport"></security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very helpful feature of WCF is the help page. It exposes all available services along with the correct URIs.

It can be located at: http://MachineName/Service.svc/help.

In my situation, it was: localhost:81/ExternalServices/WS/SPP/REST/SPPService.svc/help

This led me to see that the Web.Config file along with IIS were using HTTPS binding on port 82.

Comment: Unfortunately the WCF `help` feature doesn't play nicely with WCF REST. In my case, I have a WCF service that accepts both URI Template query-string parameters and a `Stream` which is supported by WCF REST, but not WCF's metadata/help provider (which is intended for SOAP, not REST) so it complains  and refuses to provide information about *any* WCF service in the system. Ugh (I'm glad WCF is dead now).

Comment: @Dai A service is easily created to parse the attributes on methods registered in System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes for all your services and provide the same information as the WCF help feature. I have a similar setup to yours and it's how I overcame it.

Comment: @Dai A service is easily created to duplicate the help output table of contents for services registered in System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes and provide the same information as the WCF help feature. Simply displaying a hyperlink to the service's built-in help URL accesses the normal help listing. I have a similar setup to yours and it's how I overcame it.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when IIS was configured to allow HTTPS connections and the associated security certificate had expired. The failed services were also configured to require a secure "transport" binding (to support HTTPS connections).
The errors were found in the Windows Application event log and reflected an HTTP 404 error when a request was made to an affected service.
After removing the HTTPS bindings from IIS and removing the secure requirement from the failed services, everything started working again.